# social studio - how to by pass login?

Tags: marketing-cloud, login, social-studio

In social studio (marketing cloud), Is is possible to by-pass the login form, via http-request calling the login form from a webpage and landing to social studio as logged? If so please would you direct me to the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to bypass the login. Social Studio (formally Radian 6 and Buddy Media) was acquired by ExactTarget back in 2014. Salesforce has pretty much bolted on any acquisitions into their platform, case in point ExactTarget.

Comment: At the moment there's no option for something like SSO, what this basically comes down to if I understand correctly. There's an idea in the community you can vote on: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNLZQA2